# kafka producer parameters require one message sent to take effect

Tags: python, apache-kafka, latency, confluent-platform

I'm using confluent-kafka-python (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) to send some messages to Kafka, using Python.  I send messages infrequently, so want the latency to be really really low.

If I do this, I can get messages to appear to my consumer with about a 2ms delay:

```
conf = { "bootstrap.servers" : "kafka-test-10-01",
         "queue.buffering.max.ms" : 0, 
         'batch.num.messages': 1, 
          'queue.buffering.max.messages': 100, 
              "default.topic.config" : {"acks" : 0 }}
p = confluent_kafka.Producer(**conf)
p.produce(...)
```

BUT: the latency only drops to near zero after I've sent a first message with this new producer.  Subsequent messages have latency near the 2ms mark.

The first message though has around a 1 second latency.  Why?

Comment: Does the topic already exist before you publish? If not then the extra time could be the time needed to autocreate the topic on the broker before the first messsge is published.

Answer (score 3):

Magnus Edenhill, the author of librdkafka, documented some useful parameters to set to decrease latency in any librdkafka client:

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/How-to-decrease-message-latency

You don't show your consumer parameters but from your description it sounds like the consumer is polling and rightly getting nothing (null messages) before the first message is published and so it then waits the default 500 ms `fetch.error.backoff.ms` interval before trying to poll again and getting the first message. After that the messages are probably coming fast enough that the error back off is not triggered. Perhaps try setting `fetch.error.backoff.ms` lower and see if that helps.

Comment: There are not interesting settings in the consumer.  I don't think your answer is right, because if I start a consumer, and leave it running, it always depends on the *producer* as to whether or not there is a delay.

Comment: I created a producer, and had it send a message.  Then I created a new consumer, with auto.offset.reset='latest'.  Started the consumer polling.  First message had short 3ms delay.   So issue is clearly on the producer side, that first message is always delayed.  Any other ideas?  Note that it's not critical, just curious.

Comment: Lastly, messages are sent very slowly because I'm sending them manually from a python interpreter (producer side).  consumer is just polling.  config for consumer:  
conf = { "bootstrap.servers" : server,
         "group.id" : "deb-9",
         "broker.version.fallback" : "0.8.2.2",
         "client.id" : "some-deb-id23",
         "default.topic.config" :
             { 'auto.offset.reset' : 'latest',
               }}